# awk prepend and append line of file

Tags: awk, sed, line, editing

I want to prepend and append a certain line of a file using awk.

Example:

Say i have a file with 5 lines, i want to awk the 3rd line and put "hello" at the beginning and "goodbye" at the end.

example file.

```
1. foo
2. foo
3. foo
4. foo
5. foo
```

output result `hello 3. foo goodbye` and delete all other lines 1, 2, 4, 5,

Ive tried 
`awk 'NR==3 {print $0" goodbye"}' <file>`

this appends the line with goodbye but i cannot figure out how to prepend the line with "hello"

Ive tried BEGIN and END in the command but unsure how to treat NR==3 ?

Desired output should be..

`hello 3. foo goodbye`

final output result `hello 3. foo goodbye` and delete all other lines 1, 2, 4, 5,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could you please try following. To print all lines only 3rd line with additional details.

```
awk 'FNR==3{print "hello " $0 " goodbye";next} 1' Input_file
```

***OR***

```
awk 'FNR==3{$0="hello " $0 " goodbye"} 1'  Input_file
```

***In case you want to print only 3rd edited line try:***

```
awk 'FNR==3{print "hello " $0 " goodbye"}' Input_file
```

---

---

In case you want to print only 3rd line with use of `BEGIN` and `END` as per your attempt then try following.

```
awk 'BEGIN{ORS=" ";printf "hello "} FNR==3; END{printf("%s\n","goodbye")}' Input_file
```

Comment: Thankyou RavinderSingh - awk 'FNR==3{print "hello " $0 " goodbye"}' Input_file is what i was looking for.

Comment: @clusterF, Your welcome, cheers and happy learning on this great site SO.

Answer (score 3):

In your case it's easier to go with `sed` command substitution (besides `sed` allows to modify the file in-place: basically with `-i` option):

```
$ sed '3 s/.*/hello & goodbye/' file
1. foo
2. foo
hello 3. foo goodbye
4. foo
5. foo
```

Comment: GNU awk allows modifying "inplace" just like GNU sed does. The main difference between the two tools for this is that with awk you don't have to beware of backreferences in the text you're adding but that doesn't matter with this specific text.